# ICS taste for apps on SDK less than 11

Tags: android, themes, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Recently i have seen some android apps that runs on SDK < 3.0 but they have the same look of ICS applications.

Here is an example:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hubalek.android.reborn.beta

If you run this app on an old platform (2.x) you still get the feel of ICS.

So, Does any body know how to do this ?

Also, I have seen a related link on android.com but i couldn't make good use of it.
Here is the link:
http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Thanks very much :)

Comment: http://actionbarsherlock.com/ gives a "taste" of ics :D, combined with support library you can have honeycomb+ actionbar/tabs

Answer (score 0):

For functionality, Use [V4 Support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) for fragments and Loaders. ActionBar isn't supprted but can be faked. 
For the looks, Download Holo theme resources, import and use them in your app style/drawables.